# jenkins dynamic node and maven setup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to deploy Spring boot application with React frontend and the requirement is to install npm and maven on the go in the jenkinsfile and deploy. so we don't have to depend on jenkins specific node version or maven version.

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems like the job for a container. Build a container with the right version of npm and maven, store it in a container repository, then use that built container to execute your job.

Comment: I know I can do that I was just wondering if I can do it without containers.

Comment: You can configure Jenkins to autoinstall both on the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the Kubernetes ephemeral environment which gave us the flexibility to use any version of maven, java and node.